# How to send post values with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I send data from form with several inputs to a php script? Using POST method ofc. For example I've such form:

```html
<form action="register.php" method="POST" name="registerform">
    <span class="login">Nazwa użytkownika:</span>
    <input type="text" class="login" placeholder="twój login" name="username">
    <span class="login">E-mail</span>
    <input type="text" class="login" placeholder="twój email" name="email">
    <span class="login">Hasło</span>
    <input type="password" class="login" placeholder="twoje hasło" name="password">
    <span class="login">Powtórz Hasło</span>
    <input type="password" class="login" placeholder="powtórz hasło" name="repassword">
    <input type="submit" value="Rejestruj" class="button">
</form>
```

How to send this all to register.php which is placed in same folder?

Comment: you can use either $.post or $.ajax. http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    form = $('form[name="registerform"]');
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

using jquery.post()

here is the [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialize() method

```
var str = $('form[name="registerform"]').serialize();
```

Then send the data using a ajax request  `$.ajax`  or `$.post`

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'yoururl'
   type : 'post',
   data : str,
   success : function(data){

   } 
})
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after property list  

type : 'post',